# How do you add new columns with pandas library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

*This is an updated version of a previous question*

I was having some trouble with csv files and pandas. I would like to create a new column, that being a multiplication of the previous one. For instance ['price', 'pricex2'] [[2,4],[6,12]] and so on, how could I do that?

I've got this piece of code which does not add a new column, it is suposed to update the current one, and evenso it does not work.

```
   df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
   df['Jewerly_name_price'] = df['Jewerly_name_price']*2
   print(df)
```

Plus, I have a € at the end of each price and to multiply the values x2 I would need to get rid of that, I got answered to this already but I don't know how to implement it in the addition of the new column.

```
price = 2.45€ 
numericalPrice = float(price[:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col0':[1,2,3]})
```

You can add a new column `col1` to the `df` by:

```
df = df.assign(col1 = df.col0*2)
```

You can also do more complicated things, such as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col0':["1€","2€","3€"]})
df = df.assign(col1 = df.col0.apply(lambda row: f'{int(row[:-1])*2}€'))
```

where the [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) function and [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) have been used.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying a column of strings as in `df['Jewerly_name_price']*2` will just concatenate the string next to each other as many times. In order to get rid of the '€' and multiply the value at the same time, you can do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'price': ['2.45€', '3.00€']})

def mul_price(price: str, mul_val=2):
    price_f = float(price[:-1])
    return f"{price_f * mul_val:.2f}€"

df['pricex2'] = df['price'].apply(mul_price)

#Result:
   price pricex2
0  2.45€   4.90€
1  3.00€   6.00€
```

Or, first get rid of the '€', convert to float, then multiply:

```
def price_to_float(price: str):
    return float(price[:-1])

df['price_float'] = df['price'].apply(price_to_float)
df['pricex2_float'] = df['price_float'] * 2

#Result:
   price  price_float  pricex2_float
0  2.45€         2.45            4.9
1  3.00€         3.00            6.0
```

Comment: Thank you, very useful! But sorry I forgot to add, the price values are in the second column, how could I substitute your df = pd.DataFrame({'price': ['2.45€', '3.00€']}) to make it use the second column of my file? Obviously not including the header. Thanks again for the help

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If your 'second column' has a specific name, just replace `price` by the name of your second column. You could also do `df['pricex2'] = df.iloc[:, 1].apply(mul_price)`, where `df.iloc[:, 1]` selects the second column

Comment: This is how I have adapted your code but it raises a key error: import pandas as pd

csvfile = open("D:\\leomu\\Documents\\Python projects\\Bots\\DropShipper\\WebScrapper\\Shein_data_test_run.csv")

df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)

def Price_Converter(price: str, multiplyer=2):
    numericalPrice = float(price[:-1])
    return f"{numericalPrice * multiplyer:.2f}€"

df['pricex2'] = df['Jewerly_name_price'].apply(Price_Converter)

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to indent the text to make it look neater in the comment section

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function to do the price calculation, then use `pd.apply()` like belows:

```
def multiply_price(row):
    string_price = row['Jewerly_name_price']
    price = float(string_price[:-1])

    # Change the express below to the data format of your need.
    # Here we are returning a string that is a double (twice) of the
    # original price with a '€' symbol at the end.
    # But of course, we can simple return a float without a '€'.
    return f'{price * 2}€'

df['Jewerly_name_price'] = df.apply(lambda row: multiply_price(row), axis=1)
```

[image: Define an example dataframe]

[image: Define a function to do the price calculation]

[image: Apply the function to get price calculated]